# How to replace Entire full view of div with another div without page movement using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, fadein

Hi All i am facing a problem while replacing the content of one div entirely with another div. Here is my div structure below

```
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="events">

    <div class="events-info" style="display:none;">

         <div class="tab-info">

            <div class="bat-chat"><a href="javascript:OpenGallery();" class="btn btn-warning">Bat &amp; Chat Gallery</a></div>

         </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bat-chat-gal" style="position:relative;">
```

If you see above ones there two divs with class names `events-info` and `bat-chat-gal`. Now what i am trying to do is when you click on button called `Bat & Chat gallery` in `events-info` class i am calling below javascript function called `OpenGallery()` and the code for that is below. In the `OpenGallery` function i am fading out `events-info` class and fading in `bat-chat-gal` in the same place. Here comes my problem while trying to fade in second div it's first starting at the end of the first div and then it's coming up So it's looks like page movement. How to replace without happening that using some animation.

```
function OpenGallery()
{
    $('.events-info').fadeOut();
    $('.bat-chat-gal').fadeIn(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write function like below

```
function OpenGallery()
 {
    $('.events-info').fadeOut(function(){
        $('.bat-chat-gal').fadeIn();
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

when want no animation then simple use **[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** and **[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

```
 $('.events-info').hide();
 $('.bat-chat-gal').show(3000);
```

Comment: here i clearly mentioned the problem it's not animation problem. When i try to fade in or show second div it first starting at the end of first div content and then it's replacing. Thats bad right